# Server acts weird after reboot and local IP changes

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

OS: Ubuntu server 16.04.

So I changed my local IP's from class c to class a. Now I get a weird issue on the server.

(I connect to the server using the set statically IP on SSH from a local PC)

After a reboot it can't reach the WAN. if I try to ping 8.8.8.8 I get this
`From <old class c. IP> icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

ifconfig shows it's using the new statically set class a IP.

Temp fix:
`dhclient -r -v <interface> && rm /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.* ; dhclient -v <interface>`
This returns

```
dhclient -v <interface>
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/<interface>
Sending on   LPF/<interface>
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPRELEASE on <interface> to <gateway IP> port 67 (xid=0x4cf127f2)
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/<interface>
Sending on   LPF/<interface>
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on <interface> to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x72c4ab2e)
DHCPREQUEST of <the new statically set IP> on <interface> to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2eabc472)
DHCPOFFER of <the new statically set IP> from <gateway IP>
DHCPACK of <the new statically set IP> from <gateway IP>
bound to <the new statically set IP> -- renewal in 18113 seconds.
```

But it's just temp, reboot and the issue is back.

how do I solve this?

Comment: "I changed my local IP's from class c to class a"? How, exactly did you do that? It seems like network nonsense.

Comment: I changed my local network, from a class C to a class A. followed up by changing the IP of the server to a new IP on the class A range, how is this nonsense?